# jQuery check if mouse is over

Tags: jquery

I need help making jQuery check if mouse is over an element.

I need this to work like the navigation in: http://mashable.com.

I have this:

```
<div id="main_nav">
  <ul>
<li href="#tab1">Nav Tab 1</li>
<li href="#tab2">Nav Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main_nav_expansion">
  <ul class="navtab" id="tab1">
    <li>Submenu Title Here
   <ul>
     <li>Sublink Option</li>
     <li>Sublink Option</li>
   </ul>
</li>
  </ul><!-- end navtab 1 -->
  <ul class="navtab" id="tab2">
    <li>Submenu Title Here
   <ul>
     <li>Sublink Option</li>
     <li>Sublink Option</li>
   </ul>
</li>
  </ul><!-- end navtab 2 -->
 </div>
```

I wrote this jQuery, but I can't get the ul.navtab to stay open when you move you mouse out of either "Nav Tab 1" or "Nav Tab 2". I tried to write conditional statements within the callback function to check if mouse is over element, but it doesn't work.

This is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   $('ul.navtab').hide();

   $('#main_nav ul li').hover(function(){
   $('#main_nav ul li.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass("active");
   var activeNavTab = $(this).attr("href");
   $(activeNavTab).addClass("active").slideDown();
   },function(){
   if($("ul.navtab").is(":hover")){
   $("ul.navtab").show();
   }else{
      $("ul.navtab").slideUp();
      $('#main_nav ul li.active').removeClass('active');
   }
});
```

Comment: Html is invalid `<li href='xxxxx'`, lis don't have href attributes.

Comment: that part works well, it grabs the attribute in jquery:    var activeNavTab = $(this).attr("href");

Comment: Yes, it works. That doesn't mean that it's valid code. jQuery doesn't validate for you. Instead of href, use id.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/

Comment: @isherwood, agreed. Just because something "works" is not a good enough reason to use it if it's also invalid, particularly when there are valid solutions readily available.

Comment: That's very close, looks great! Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks for the tips about the invalid attributes! All I've learned about code I've learned in online communities because of comments like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$('ul.navtab').hide();

   $('#main_nav ul li').hover(function () {
      $('#main_nav ul li.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass("active");
      var activeNavTab = $(this).attr("href");
      $(activeNavTab).siblings().removeClass("active").hide();
      $(activeNavTab).addClass("active").slideDown();
  });
  $('.navtab').on({
    mouseleave: function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('this').fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

I don't think there is any need for the callback.

[**checkout the final fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/YsNCB/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I need the expanded panel to appear when you move your mouse over the main tab, and stay visible while you hover over it, then it should disappear when you move out.

Comment: It looks better, but it's still not doing what I need it to do. Now the panels (ul.navtabs) are bouncing up and down, and they don't close  up when you move your mouse away.

Comment: use `.hide()` instead of `.slideup()` see the answer and fiddle for one more time.

Comment: Ah, that works now! I redo the fiddle css a bit to show you where I was going with this. Thanks!  http://jsfiddle.net/aSkNM/3/